# Error while inserting data in a Set Swift 4

Tags: swift, set

I am trying to insert multiple values in a Set. So, I did this

```
    var skuSet: Set = Set<String>()
       { 
            (response, error) in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error \(error.debugDescription)")
            }

            else
            {

                if let result = response.arrayObject as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> 
                {
                    self.coinsArr = result

                    let  multiple = result.compactMap{ $0["sku"] as? String }

                    self.skuSet.insert(multiple)
                }
             }
```

But, the `insert` line throws the error

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'.

Any help?

Comment: convert your multiple into a set and do an union

Comment: The code is not clear, please reformat it.

Comment: Reformatted Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert` is for a single item. Use `formUnion` to insert multiple items from a `Sequence` into a `Set`

```
self.skuSet.formUnion(multiple)
```

And if you want to replace the contents of the set with the `multiple` array simply write

```
self.skuSet = Set(multiple)
```

Comment: Thanks, man again! Can you please tell me some source from where I can read and learn about these as I do not want to go back to loops. : )

Comment: See other answers for more details.

Comment: For example search google for *Swift map filter*. There are a few good articles.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [compactMap(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) says:

> compactMap(_:) returns an array containing the non-nil results of
>   calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

However, the documentation for set [insert(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1541375-insert) also says:

> insert(_:) inserts the given element in the set if it is not already
>   present.

You assign an array of strings to `multiple`, and expect to insert this array using `insert(_:)` but it's not possible.

Add the below function to `Set` extension in order to insert multiple elements:

```
func insert(_ elements: [Set.Element]) {
    elements.forEach { (element) in
        self.insert(element)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use [formUnion(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853361-formunion):

```
self.skuSet.formUnion(multiple)
```

...or use its immutable version, [union(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853826-union):

```
var skuSetUnionMultiple = self.skuSet.union(multiple)
```